# Calculate the integral $\int_{\frac{5\pi}{2}}^{\frac{9\pi}{2}} \cos^4{\theta}\;d\theta.$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

> Calculate the integral $$\int_{\frac{5\pi}{2}}^{\frac{9\pi}{2}} \cos^4{\theta}\;d\theta.$$

So I know that $$\cos^2{\theta} = \Big(\frac{e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta}}{2}\Big)^2 = \frac{1}{4}e^{-2i\theta} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4}e^{2i\theta}.$$

But where do I go from here?

Edit: How do I go about solving the integral using Parseval's Theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** First, note that the integral is over an interval of length $\require{cancel}2 \pi$ and that the integrand is periodic with period (dividing) $2 \pi$.

Now, squaring the identity you pointed out gives
$$\cos^4 \theta = (\cos^2 \theta)^2 = \left[\frac{1}{4}(e^{2 i \theta} + 2 + e^{-2 i \theta})\right]^2 = \frac{3}{8} + \sum a_k e^{k i \theta},$$
for some nonzero integers $k$ and coefficients $a_k$.

> For $k \neq 0$ the antiderivative of $e^{k i \theta}$ is $-\frac{i}{k} e^{k i \theta}$, so its integral over an interval $I$ of length $2 \pi$ is zero, and $$\int_I \cos^4 \theta \,d\theta = \int_I \left(\frac{3}{8} + \sum a_k e^{k i \theta}\right) d\theta = \frac{3}{8} \int_I d\theta + a_k \cancelto{0}{\sum \int_I e^{k i \theta} d\theta} = \frac{3}{8} \cdot 2 \pi = \frac{3 \pi}{4} .$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use that $$\cos^4(x)=\frac{1}{8}(3+4\cos(2x)+\cos(4x))$$
For your consideration: the result should be $$\frac{3\pi}{4}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Choose $y=x-\dfrac{5\pi}2$

to find $$I=\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^4t\ dt$$

By symmetry,

$$2I=\int_0^{\pi/2}(\sin^4t+\cos^4t)dt$$

Now $\sin^4t+\cos^4t=1-2\sin^2t\cos^2t=1-\dfrac{\sin^22t}2=1-\dfrac{1-\cos4t}4$

Answer (score 1):

With Parseval: $$\cos^2(\theta) = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cos(2\theta) $$
leads to
$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(\cos^2\theta\right)^2\,d\theta = 2\pi\cdot\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 + \pi\cdot\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{3\pi}{4}$$
and your integral is the same as the LHS of the last line since $\cos\theta$ is $2\pi$-periodic.

Comment: I see that $2\pi$ on the RHS comes from cancelling the $\frac{1}{2\pi}$, but how do you end up with $2\pi\cdot \big(\frac{1}{2}\big)^2 + \pi\cdot \big(\frac{1}{2}\big)^2$? Where do the $\frac{1}{2}$'s come from?

Comment: @wednesdaymiko: $\frac{1}{2},0,\frac{1}{2}$ are the coefficients of the Fourier cosine series of $\cos^2\theta$, and if $$ f(\theta)=c_0+\sum_{n\geq 1}c_n \cos(n\theta)$$ then $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(\theta)^2\,d\theta = 2\pi c_0^2+\pi\sum_{n\geq 1} c_n^2.$$

Comment: Oh right, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, i hesitated to post this, but let it be. Complex analysis. Trigonometry becomes algebra. The integral on the given period interval $J$ of length $2\pi$ of $\cos$ and $\cos^4$, can be rephrased as an integral on the unit circle $C$ centered in the origin, using $\cos t =\frac 12(e^{it}+e^{-it})$. We substitute $z=e^{it}$ and use the residue theorem.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{J}\cos^4 t\; dt
&=
\int_{J}\left(\frac 12\left(e^{it}+e^{-it}\right)\right)^4 \; \frac 1{ie^{it}}\; d(e^{it})
\\
&=
\int_C \left(\frac 12\left(z+\frac 1z\right)\right)^4 \; \frac 1{iz}\; dz
\\
&=2\pi i\cdot\operatorname{Residue}_{z=0}
\left(\frac 12\left(z+\frac 1z\right)\right)^4 \; \frac 1{iz}
\\
&=2\pi \;\left(\frac 12\right)^4 \binom 42=\frac {3\pi}4\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
(We had to fish the coefficient of $z$ to the power zero from $\left(z+\frac 1z\right)^4$.)
The only advantage of this solution is the immediate generalization,
$$
\int_{J}\cos^{2n} t\; dt
=
2\pi\; \left(\frac 12\right)^{2n} \binom {2n}n\ .
$$
But it is simpler to get it from the simplest solution in this party of answers, the one of Travis. (+1 from me above.)